# Building an inline Angular application

Tags: angular, webpack

I would like to enable building my Angular app in a way that produces output HTML that can be put as part of another page, meaning without the `html` and `body` tags, just `app-root` etc.

The page I am trying to deploy on is a CMS, and my Angular app needs to be built in a way that produces an output HTML file containing just `app-root`, script tags for JS files and a function which places the CSS `link` tag in the header. I have worked out how I want this to look, but have not found a way of tweaking webpack to replace the `link` and `script` tags with the cache-busting names on build.

I am reading up on [this page](https://v5.angular.io/guide/webpack) to learn more, but feel the docs are quite obscure. Will post updates as soon as I learn more.

Anyone tried to do something similar to this?